# Images (either PNGs or WebPs) suddenly have black backgrounds instead of transparent

Tags: png, gatsby, webp

I just changed my computer at work. Up until today, on my old PC that ran Windows 8, and when developing my Gatsby site on local, everything was fine. Since the switch (I'm now on W10) alkl my images with transparency have now lost their transparent layer and are black instead. [Before-after Example](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/297064/images/ss.jpg)

This happens only on local ; the site has two hosting instances, staging on AWS, prod on Netlify, and they're both okay. Also, the image appears fine when I open it in a new tab ; the black happens only when viewing the site in full. It happens on all browsers though.

I haven't changed the gatsby-configs so I really don't know if the problem is caused by Windows, or Gatsby, or the browsers, or... Although my guess is it's with gatsby-image or gatsby-transformer-remark, because other PNGs called with a simple import don't have this problem.

I've tried updating my libwebp library on Windows but couldn't find a version higher than 0.19

Here are my plugins from gatsby-config.js :

```
plugins: [{
            resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
            options: {
                name: "src",
                path: `${__dirname}/src/`
            }
        }, {
            resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
            options: {
                name: "dsp",
                path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/dsp/`
            }
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",
            options: {
                plugins: [{
                    resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
                    options: {
                        maxWidth: 1200,
                        withWebp: true
                    },
                }, ],
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-catch-links"
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-transformer-sharp"
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sharp"
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet"
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-manifest",
            options: {
                name: "Mysite",
                short_name: "Mysite",
                start_url: "/",
                background_color: "#FFFFFF",
                theme_color: "#001464",
                display: "minimal-ui",
                icon: "static/icons/icon.png"
            }
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sitemap"
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager",
            options: {
                id: "GTM-MRM8KCP",

                // Include GTM in development.
                // Defaults to false meaning GTM will only be loaded in production.
                includeInDevelopment: true,

                // datalayer to be set before GTM is loaded
                // should be an object or a function that is executed in the browser
                // Defaults to null
                defaultDataLayer: {
                    platform: "gatsby"
                },

                // Specify optional GTM environment details.
                // gtmAuth: "YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ENVIRONMENT_AUTH_STRING",
                gtmPreview: "Mysite React Preview",
                // dataLayerName: "YOUR_DATA_LAYER_NAME",
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-nprogress",
            options: {
                color: "#001464",
                showSpinner: false
            }
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-source-wordpress",
            options: {
                baseUrl: "mysite.com",
                protocol: "https",
                hostingWPCOM: false,
                useACF: false,
                concurrentRequests: 10,
                verboseOutput: true,
                excludedRoutes: [
                    "/*/*/comments",
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-offline"
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sass"
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms"
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-plugin-svgr"
        }
    ]
```

Here's the graphQL fragment I'm using for pretty much all the concerned images :

```
fragment basicFluid on File {
    childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 1600) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
        }
    }
}
```

On the page, I query the image as such :

```
query IndexImages {
    TimesSquare: file(relativePath: { eq: "assets/images/bg/home_time_square_bg.png" }) {
        ...basicFluid
    }
}
```

And finally my package.json dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^4.3.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.0.48",
    "gatsby-cli": "^2.4.6",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.0.20",
    "gatsby-paginate": "^1.0.16",
    "gatsby-plugin-catch-links": "^2.0.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-fonts": "^0.0.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^2.1.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.0.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^2.0.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "^3.0.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-nprogress": "^2.0.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-page-transitions": "^1.0.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.15",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-svgr": "^2.0.2",
    "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers": "^2.0.11",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.0.3",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.7",
    "gatsby-source-stripe": "^1.2.1",
    "gatsby-source-wordpress": "^2.0.93",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.1.12",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.8",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "hashmap": "^2.3.0",
    "i18n-react": "^0.7.0",
    "mobx": "^5.6.0",
    "netlify-cms": "^2.8.0",
    "netlify-identity-widget": "^1.4.14",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "opentracing": "^0.14.3",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-countup": "^4.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-hubspot-form": "^1.3.7",
    "react-lazy-load": "^3.0.13",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.3.0",
    "react-md": "^1.5.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.47",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.11",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.0",
    "react-swipeable-views-core": "^0.13.0",
    "typeface-roboto": "^0.0.54",
    "utf8": "^3.0.0",
    "yarn": "^1.9.4"
},
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Experiencing the same problem when from Windows Powershell

Answer (score 5):

You can actually add this attribute to the `StaticImage` component: `placeholder= 'none'`, or go to the gatsby-config.js file and add this:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
  options: {
    defaults: {
      formats: [`auto`, `webp`, `png`, `jpg`],
      placeholder: `none`,
      breakpoints: [750, 1080, 1366, 1920],
      backgroundColor: `white`,
      tracedSVGOptions: {},
      blurredOptions: {},
      jpgOptions: {},
      pngOptions: {},
      webpOptions: {},
      avifOptions: {},
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I have the similar problem.
My solution is remove `srcSetWebp` from `query`. I don't know why, but It just works.

Before:

```
query {
    allImageSharp {
      edges {
        node {
          fluid(maxWidth: 110) {
            aspectRatio
            originalName
            sizes
            src
            srcSet
            srcWebp
            srcSetWebp
            tracedSVG
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

After:

```
query {
    allImageSharp {
      edges {
        node {
          fluid(maxWidth: 110) {
            aspectRatio
            originalName
            sizes
            src
            srcSet
            srcWebp
            tracedSVG
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope you can find someway for your solution.